# Feeds do chat não funcionam

Tags: bug, status-recusado, chat

Em todas salas de chat temos um [**Feed**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) para as mensagens marcadas com estrelas, no entanto os feeds das salas [**estouro de pilha**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) e [**debate de pilha**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57786/debate-da-pilha) não funcionam:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/11910
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/57786

Recebo a mensagem:

> TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL

Conforme o navegador Opera:

[image: fault in the feed > TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL]

Outras salas fora do SOpt parece funcionar normalmente.

O problema ocorre devido a tag dentro do FEED estar em **HTTP** quando deveria estar em **HTTPS**, isto:

```
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/57786" />
```

Deveria ser isto:

```
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/57786" />
```

Vejam que nem passa no validador de feeds:

- https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fchat.stackexchange.com%2Ffeeds%2Frooms%2Fstarred%2F57786

---

## English Translation

**Title:** Chat feeds do not work

In all chat rooms we have a [**Feed**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSS) for starred messages. However, the feeds for the rooms [**estouro de pilha**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11910/estouro-de-pilha) and [**debate de pilha**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57786/debate-da-pilha) don't work:

- https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/11910
- https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/57786

I get the message:

> TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL

In Opera browser:

[image: fault in the feed > TypeError: Failed to construct 'URL': Invalid URL]

Other rooms outside SOpt appear to be working as usual.

The problem occurs due to the tag inside the FEED being in **HTTP** when it should be in **HTTPS**. This:

```
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/57786" />
```

Should be this:

```
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="https://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/57786" />
```

See how it doesn't work in the feed validator:

- https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi?url=https%3A%2F%2Fchat.stackexchange.com%2Ffeeds%2Frooms%2Fstarred%2F57786

Comment: Os dois links para feeds fornecidos funcionam para mim.

Comment: Pra mim os dois funcionam também.

Comment: @JNat parece que ocorre somente no Opera.

Comment: @JNat achei o problema, rodei no validador da w3, a tag `<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/57786" />` está com HTTP ao invés de HTTPS.

Comment: Jnat e @LINQ vocês não notaram o erro porque provavelmente o seus leitores de feed não validam conforme a tag `<link rel="self">`

Comment: Não consigo reproduzir o erro nem no Firefox, nem no Chrome, nem no Safari. Mesmo assim, traduzi a publicação para que um dev possa dar uma olhadela.

Comment: @JNat nem todos navegadores fazem a validação, e depende muito do leitor de FEED que usa, existem vários leitores mesmo, com diferentes comportamentos, algums mais STRICT outros menos. O validador da W3 é o melhor caminho para determinar a falha e não navegadores em si, afinal um mesmo navegador pode ter sistema de inscrição de feeds nativos ou não (dependendo de add-ons ou serviços webs)

Comment: If it's working for other rooms, I highly doubt this has anything to do with the "self" link. My guess is that there's some specific bit of content in both rooms that Opera isn't parsing properly; I don't have Opera handy to test with though.